# Mongodb query not working as expected when using limit clause

Tags: mongodb, sorting, optimization, projection

When I am running following execution plan for following query with limit clause, in execution plan given below totalDataSizeSorted is 71561167 KB but when I run it without limit clause totalDataSizeSorted is 25624890 KB and returned records are much higher.

Query with limit:

```
db.mycollection.find({ $and: [ { state: "Active" }, { expires_date: { $gte: new Date(1451586600000), $lte: new Date(1666003832377) } }
, { $or: [ { last_checked: { $lte: new Date(1666003832377) } }, { last_checked: { $exists: false } } ] }, { $or: [ 
 { processingState: { $exists: true } } ] } ] },{_id:1,last_checked:1 }).sort({last_checked:1}).limit(10000).explain("executionStats");
```

Corresponding ExecutionPlan:

```json
{
        "explainVersion" : "1",
       
        "executionStats" : {
                "executionSuccess" : true,
                "nReturned" : 10000,
                "executionTimeMillis" : 1066,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 458892,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 458892,
                "executionStages" : {
                        "stage" : "PROJECTION_SIMPLE",
                        "nReturned" : 10000,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 150,
                        "works" : 468894,
                        "advanced" : 10000,
                        "transformBy" : {
                                "_id" : 1,
                                "last_checked" : 1
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "SORT",
                                "nReturned" : 10000,
                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 152,
                                "works" : 468894,
                                "advanced" : 10000,
                                "sortPattern" : {
                                        "last_checked" : 1
                                },
                                "memLimit" : 104857600,
                                "limitAmount" : 10000,
                                "type" : "simple",
                                "totalDataSizeSorted" : 71561167,
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                                        "nReturned" : 418149,
                                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 127,
                                        "works" : 458893,
                                        "advanced" : 418149,
                                        "docsExamined" : 458892,
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Query without limit:

```
db.mycollection.find({ $and: [ { state: "Active" }, { expires_date: { $gte: new Date(1451586600000), $lte: new Date(1666003832377) } }
, { $or: [ { last_checked: { $lte: new Date(1666003832377) } }, { last_checked: { $exists: false } } ] }, { $or: [ 
 { processingState: { $exists: true } } ] } ] },{_id:1,last_checked:1 }).sort({last_checked:1}).explain("executionStats");
```

Corresponding ExecutionPlan:

```json
{
    "explainVersion" : "1",
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 418149,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 1558,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 458892,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 458892,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "SORT",
            "nReturned" : 418149,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 310,
            "works" : 877043,
            "advanced" : 418149,
            "sortPattern" : {
                "last_checked" : 1
            },
            "memLimit" : 104857600,
            "type" : "simple",
            "totalDataSizeSorted" : 25624890,
            "usedDisk" : false,
            "spills" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "PROJECTION_SIMPLE",
                "nReturned" : 418149,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 235,
                "works" : 458893,
                "advanced" : 418149,
                "transformBy" : {
                    "_id" : 1,
                    "last_checked" : 1
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    
                    "nReturned" : 418149,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 214,
                    "works" : 458893,
                    "advanced" : 418149,
                    "docsExamined" : 458892
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have observed that "stage" : "PROJECTION_SIMPLE" is executing first in case of without limit clause that's why only 25624890KB data is passed to "SORT" stage but in case of query with limit clause "PROJECTION_SIMPLE" stage is being executed after "SORT" stage, that's why 71561167KB data is used for sorting.

How can we force query engine to execute "PROJECTION_SIMPLE" before "SORT" stage?

Comment: You are adding a `limit` to the cursor to get less results, it then gives you less results. why is this surprising/bad?

Comment: In sort stage, it's just opposite. When using limit, sort stage uses more data to data size to sort and when not using limit, its using less data size for sort.